# React-Native-Picker Supported version for RN V0.72.6

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, dependencies, picker

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-picker'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

above error occurred in while to compile project.

What is the supported version of React-Native-Picker for supported RN V0.72.6

Comment: Try to reinstall the package. It will solve your problem. Check [this](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/issues/446#issuecomment-1566360415)